# Hide "unread" counts on certain folders in Apple's Mail.app

Tags: apple-mail

I'm syncing my mail to Gmail, and there are certain folders, such as Spam & Trash, that I don't want to have to read, but I'd really like to hide the unread counts. (I'm talking about in the app, not in the dock -- I see how to customize what goes in the doc.) Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution for junk mail, at least. It is probably easily adaptable to trash, too. However, it is something you would do on gmail, so would affect on all your computers- I don't know if that is acceptable for your situation.

If you create a gmail filter with "Has the words: in:spam", you can tell gmail to mark spam messages as read, but otherwise process them as normal. I guess the in:trash keyword would work the same way.

Source: http://tobylaura.com/blog/2012/08/spam-coun/

Answer (score 0):

Rather than hiding, what about not synchronizing Spam & Trash? Enable the [Advanced IMAP Controls](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2008/10/new-in-labs-advanced-imap-controls.html) feature in Gmail labs?

If that's not a viable option for you, your next stop should be the [list of Mail.app plugins](http://www.hawkwings.net/plugins.htm) on hawkwings.net

Comment: I'd be happy to eliminate that stuff for this particular machine, but not for all of my machines. Thanks for the link to the plug-ins page. I see stuff for adding more info to the dock badge, but nothing for removing info from the folders list. :(